# getting name of windows component for mouse cursor position

Tags: java, windows

I am developing an application where blind person can interact with computer. I have completed the part where computer responds as per command given by user. The part where i am stuck is i want to give voice feedback as user moves the cursor for example if mouse is on `D:\` drive then user should get feedback that it's `D:\` drive....i want to do it for whole windows ...using java....I am using `jsapi`

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {               
    strEvent = "MouseClicked";
    x = e.getX();
    y = getY();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Not really something Java will be able to do, as you don't have enough access to the underlying OS architecture

Answer (score 0):

<s>You might be able to use a MouseMovementListener and on each movement event, get the position of the cursor and in some way get the component at that location, and get it's name. I'll take a look at it and edit my answer when I get to my PC.</s>

**Edit:** I don't think that java can achieve this. You *might* be able to do it with C++ or C#, *maybe*.